# using html and php date and mobile number

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am new to the html and php,I had inserted the data in the html but in the date it is displaying 0000-00-00 and in case mobile number when i entered numbers less than 9 characters it is displaying same numbers, but when i any entered 10 digits then it is displaying the default number "2147483647" same value 
And below is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
  <head>
    <title>STUDENT_DATA</title>
   </head>
   <body>
  <form action="1.php" method="post" >
    <center>
    sname: <input type="text" name="sname" required><br></br>
    sno:<input type="text" name="sno"><br></br>
    marks:<input type="text" name="marks"><br></br>
    class:<input type="text" name="class"><br></br>
    phno:<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >
    = 48 && event.charCode <= 57'><br></br>
    DOB:<input type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" required pattern="[0-9]  
     {4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"/>
      <button>submit</button></br>
    <input type="submit" value="insert" ></center><br>
        </center>
      </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

And below is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
  if (!$connection)
{
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
  $select_db = mysql_select_db( "student",$connection);
if (!$select_db)
{
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
  error_reporting(0);
  session_start();
  $sname=$_POST['sname'];
  $sno=$_POST['sno'];
  $marks=$_POST['marks'];
  $class=$_POST['class'];
  $phno=$_POST['phno'];
  $DOB=$_POST['DOB'];
  if($sname!='' and $sno!='' and $marks!='')
{
$query = mysql_query("insert into hello1(sname, sno, marks, class, phno ,  
 DOB)
 values ('$sname', '$sno', '$marks', '$class','$phno','$DOB')");
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
 else
{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}
mysql_close($connection); 
?>
```

Is there any one to help me!!!!!!

Comment: look at your limitation in your database it could be the problem

Comment: or show us the code from your database

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: @ Blueblazer172 I had used MySQLi and PDO_MySQL instead of mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect then also it is not displaying numbers and date

Answer (score 0):

> do not use mysql_ -functions cause they are deprecated since PHP 5.5.0

the correct pattern for DOB are:

```
DOB:<input type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" 
required pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> mysql_ functions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in
> PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.


change your code like ` <html> 
  <head>
    <title>STUDENT_DATA</title>
   </head>
   <body>
  <form action="1.php" method="post" >
    <center>
    sname: <input type="text" name="sname" required><br></br>
    sno:<input type="text" name="sno"><br></br>
    marks:<input type="text" name="marks"><br></br>
    class:<input type="text" name="class"><br></br>
    phno:<input type="text" name="phno" onkeypress='return event.charCode >
    = 48 && event.charCode <= 57'><br></br>
    DOB:<input type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" 
required pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}" name="DOB"/>
      <button>submit</button></br>
    <input type="submit" value="insert" ></center><br>
        </center>
      </form>
    </body>
 </html>`

plaese try it
```

Comment: Ok @Shanu k  in case of date it is displaying,but in case of numbers it is not working...

Comment: can you please show me your code from database?or can you please change your phone number data type from int to var char?

Comment: or please use    $query = "insert into hello1(sname, sno, marks, class, phno ,  
 DOB)
 values ('$sname', '$sno', '$marks', '$class',$phno,'$DOB')";